# Set if else statements PDO

Tags: php, pdo, mysqli

How do I set the IF ELSE condition in PDO?

I want to be able to echo the results if there are records with **faced = 'N'**. OR echo 'Empty'.

```
$query = $db->prepare('SELECT student, subject FROM my_db WHERE faced = ? ORDER BY RAND() LIMIT 1');
$array = array('N');
$query->execute($array);
if ($query>0){
$result = $query->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
var_dump($result);
} else {
    echo 'Empty';
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could just execute the fetch before the check:

```
$query->execute($array);
$result = $query->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
if (count($result) > 0){
    var_dump($result);
} else {
    echo 'Empty';
}
```

Comment: @NathaliaZeed Great to hear! If it's all working for you feel free to mark the answer as accepted!

Answer (score 1):

Here ya go! do it through the query:

```
SELECT 
Student,
Subject,
Max(CASE When faced ='N' then faced else 'Empty' End) as Faced
FROM my_db 
group by student
```